# Resizable adding margins

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I am using .resizable on modals and it seems to mess with the table inside the modal. For instance, the modal is set to 800px and 10px margins and the table on the inside is 100%. When I grab the resize handle and start to move in, the left side of the table doesn't move, but the right side shrinks like 20px and stays there for the duration of the resize, and then when I resize back out it gets to the 20px mark and then goes back to the original size. How can I keep the table from shrinking in those 20px on resize and have it stay flush throughout the entire resize?

https://jsfiddle.net/n5c352qy/

```
  $( function() {
    $( "#Modal" ).resizable();
  } );

<div class="container">
<div id="Modal">
<table>
<tr><td>Tested</td></tr>
<tr><td>Tested</td></tr>
</table>
</div>

#Modal{
  max-width: 800px;
  width: 800px;
  padding: 10px;
}
table{
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}
table td{
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: Your fiddle was not working, fixed: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/e11gr9q1/

Comment: I don't think I understand. First, you have `padding` set in your CSS and not `margin`. Second it's not clear what you want to have happen. Are you trying to contain the resize or something else?

Comment: So when I click on the resize tool and start to move left, the table inside moves about 10px before the actual modal does and I can't figure out why

Comment: I don't see this happen when testing in FireFox. What do I need to do to replicate the issue?